# Modal popup based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this very close but not quite.  What I am looking for is to cycle images based on a radio button selection, this works fine.  I would also like a modal pop up on click of the image, so if I select radio selection 1, image 1 shows and is clickable to a modal, similarly for each other radio option.  Again, this is working fine.  what is not is the modal pop up based on the radio button image.

Here is the css used:

```
#piGal ul {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 2em 3em 2em;

}
#piGal img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: .5em .5em 2em .5em;
}
#piGal .outer {
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}



#piGalImg img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}


#piGalImg .outer {
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}



 /* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

The radio button (simplified) is as follows:

```
<div class="contentText">
<section>
<h5>Choose color</h5>
<ul id="radio-attribute" class="radio-attribute">           
<li class="radio-attribute">
<label for="1" class="radio-attribute">
<input type="radio" id="1" name="id[27]" value="170" onClick="change_image(this.id)">
<img src="images/silver_swatch.png" alt="GBM0911S Silver" title=" GBM0911S Silver " width="42" height="40" />
</label>
</li>

<li class="radio-attribute">
<label for="2" class="radio-attribute">
<input type="radio" id="2" name="id[27]" value="175" onClick="change_image(this.id)">
<img src="images/blue_swatch.png" alt="GBM0911B Blue" title=" GBM0911B Blue " width="45" height="40" />
</label>
</li>
</ul>       
</section>
</div>
```

And the javascript is as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

var images = ["GLAMOURFRONT.jpg","GBM0911S.png"];

function preload(arrayOfImages) {
        $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
            $('<img />').attr('src',this).appendTo('body').css('display','none');
        });
    }

    preload(images);

    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("piGal");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

        function change_image(radioID) {
            document.getElementById("piGal").innerHTML = "<img id=\"piGal\" src=\"images/"+ images[radioID] +"\" />";
        }

    // Get the modal

        img.onclick = function(){
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
            captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }

    document.querySelectorAll('label.radio-attribute img').forEach(function (radioClick) {
      radioClick.addEventListener("click", function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
      });
    });
    //-->
    </script>
```

And html for the image display:

```
    <div id="piGal" style="float: left;">

      <a href="/images/GLAMOURFRONT.jpg"><img src="images/GLAMOURFRONT.jpg" alt="image" title=" image " width="225" height="184"  id="myImg"  /></a>   

</div>
```

And html for the modal :

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
     <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('piGal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <img class="modal-content" id="piGal">
    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
    <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
```

currently as soon as the radio image is clicked, the modal opens up, without the image (stored in the image array).  Been at this a long time and am so close to a solution....

thanks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8c09e9j0/

Answer (score 0):

The modal pops up when you click the radio button because you're explicitly calling that behavior in your event listener with `modal.style.display = "block";`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('label.radio-attribute img').forEach(function (radioClick) {
      radioClick.addEventListener("click", function () {
        modal.style.display = "block"; <-- Remove this line here.
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
      });
    });
```

Another problem I saw is that when you switch images you're destroying the event listener that launches your modal on image click when you call `change_image`. Replacing the `img` tag means that the new `img` won't have the same `img.onclick` handler. You're also not replacing the `<a>` tag that wraps the `img` tag when you replace the `InnerHTML`.

To get around that you could put your listener on the `piGal` element instead:

```
  document.getElementById("piGal").onclick = function(){
    // You'll have to update this to target the image as a child of piGal.
  }
```

Also in your HTML `onClick` should be `onclick`.

Comment: The listener on the piGal element, would it just used the modal pop up then instead?

Comment: Yes, the piGal element would call the popup. The different being that instead of calling `this.src` to get the image source you'd have to find the image as a child of piGal. Something like 'this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src` - See details: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp

Comment: I was hoping to use the same idea as      modalImg.src = "<img id=\"myImg\" src=\"images/"+ images[radioID] +"\" />";  but not seeing the mage, it pops up but as undefined.  The raioID would equate to the array position for the image name.

Comment: The pop up now displays the corect image name, but not the image itself, using this:      document.getElementById("piGal").onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = "<img id=\"myImg\" src=\"images/"+ images[imageID] +"\" />";
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }

Comment: Try: `modalImg.src = "'images/' + images[imageID]";` ? Note you can mix your quotes so you don't have to esacpe.

Comment: As soon as I do that it changes to undefined.